# Quartz.NET executing job only once

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, quartz.net-2.0

I am trying to make simple scheduled job in Quartz.NET 2.0

I've read about a similar problem but it didn't work out for me.

The problem is that the job gets executed only once after the StartAt trigger.

Here is my code:

```
public EntityMappingSvc()
{
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EntityMappingJob>().WithIdentity("QueueJob").Build();
    TriggerBuilder tb = TriggerBuilder.Create();
    tb.WithIdentity("StdTrigger");
    tb.WithSimpleSchedule(a => a.WithIntervalInMinutes(1));
    tb.StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 10, 55, 0)));
    tb.ForJob(job);
    ITrigger trigger = tb.Build();
    Global.sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global.factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Global.sched = Global.factory.GetScheduler();
    Global.sched.Start();

    GC.KeepAlive(factory);
    GC.KeepAlive(sched);
}
```

The job is simple... but to test it i had to raise an error that is caught and handled separate and does not influence the actual job.

After it runs the job the first time, it gets blocked in

```
while (runnable == null && run)
{
     Monitor.Wait(this, 500);
}
if (runnable != null)
{
     ran = true;
     runnable.Run();
}
```

in the Run method in SimpleThreadPool.

Any suggestions?

PS: the application is a WCF IIS hosted service.

Edited:

```
TriggerBuilder tb = TriggerBuilder.Create();
tb.WithIdentity("StdTrigger");
tb.WithCronSchedule("0 1 * * * ?");
tb.StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 10, 45, 0)));
tb.ForJob(job);
ICronTrigger trigger = tb.Build() as ICronTrigger;
Global.sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

still not working.

same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar problem. Replace notations:

```
GC.KeepAlive(factory);
GC.KeepAlive(sched);
```

with simple static pointer to scheduler:

```
private static scheduler _scheduler;
...
_scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: I already did that, the factory and the scheduler are static in Global.asax but are public so that i can instantiate them from the service constructor.

Comment: The only difference with my case in trigger type, try cron one.

Comment: still nothing, check the edit maybe i did not use the Cron right

Comment: yeap, you have to specify repeat interval like this via slash `"0 1/1 * * * ?`", which means every minute.

Comment: it is aliiiiiiiiiiiiiiive!!! i've been struggling with this for the past 2 days... Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue, the reason your original job was only running the first time with the simple schedule is you need to specify .RepeatForever()

```
tb.WithSimpleSchedule(a => a.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever());
```

With the cronschedule you don't need to specify reapeatforever but personally I prefer using the simple schedule where possible as it is a lot more readable.